# making a fully labelled scatter plot using R

Tags: r

can someone help me show me how I could make a fully labelled scatter plot for 2 variables, showing the axis labels with units(such as "cm"), and also including the chart title. Forexample, how would i make a fully labelled scatter plot including all the above listed features for age and height, using the following data using R?

```
 Distance Age Height Coning
1      21.4  18    3.3    Yes
2      13.9  17    3.4    Yes
3      23.9  16    2.9    Yes
4       8.7  18    3.6     No
5     241.8   6    0.7     No
6      44.5  17    1.3    Yes
7      30.0  15    2.5    Yes
8      32.3  16    1.8    Yes
9      31.4  17    5.0     No
10     32.8  13    1.6     No
11     53.3  12    2.0     No
12     54.3   6    0.9     No
13     96.3  11    2.6     No
14    133.6   4    0.6     No
15     32.1  15    2.3     No
16     57.9  12    2.4    Yes
17     30.8  17    1.8     No
18     59.9   7    0.8     No
19     42.7  15    2.0    Yes
20     20.6  18    1.7    Yes
21     62.0   8    1.3     No
22     53.1   7    1.6     No
23     28.9  16    2.2    Yes
24    177.4   5    1.1     No
25     24.8  14    1.5    Yes
26     75.3  14    2.3    Yes
27     51.6   7    1.4     No
28     36.1   9    1.1     No
29    116.1   6    1.1     No
30     28.1  16    2.5    Yes
31      8.7  19    2.2    Yes
32    105.1   6    0.8     No
33     46.0  15    3.0    Yes
34    102.6   7    1.2     No
35     15.8  15    2.2     No
36     60.0   7    1.3     No
37     96.4  13    2.6     No
38     24.2  14    1.7     No
39     14.5  15    2.4     No
40     36.6  14    1.5     No
41     65.7   5    0.6     No
42    116.3   7    1.6     No
43    113.6   8    1.0     No
44     16.7  15    4.3    Yes
45     66.0   7    1.0     No
46     60.7   7    1.0     No
47     90.6   7    0.7     No
48     91.3   7    1.3     No
49     14.4  18    3.1    Yes
50     72.8  14    3.0    Yes
```

Comment: Are you looking for a basic x, y scatter plot if yes, http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/plot.default.html will help

Comment: Adding an small example of your data will help people answer your question. I edited this question, as i generated the data for this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801803/how-can-i-summarizing-data-statistics-using-r) already. Follow this link, regarding [how to make a great reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With base graphics:

```
df <- read.table(header=T, sep=" ", text="
Yes Distance Age Height Coning
1 21.4 18 3.3 Yes
2 13.9 17 3.4 Yes
3 23.9 16 2.9 Yes
4 8.7 18 3.6 No
5 241.8 6 0.7 No
6 44.5 17 1.3 Yes
7 30.0 15 2.5 Yes
8 32.3 16 1.8 Yes
9 31.4 17 5.0 No
10 32.8 13 1.6 No
11 53.3 12 2.0 No
12 54.3 6 0.9 No
13 96.3 11 2.6 No
14 133.6 4 0.6 No
15 32.1 15 2.3 No
16 57.9 12 2.4 Yes
17 30.8 17 1.8 No
18 59.9 7 0.8 No
19 42.7 15 2.0 Yes
20 20.6 18 1.7 Yes
21 62.0 8 1.3 No
22 53.1 7 1.6 No
23 28.9 16 2.2 Yes
24 177.4 5 1.1 No
25 24.8 14 1.5 Yes
26 75.3 14 2.3 Yes
27 51.6 7 1.4 No
28 36.1 9 1.1 No
29 116.1 6 1.1 No
30 28.1 16 2.5 Yes
31 8.7 19 2.2 Yes
32 105.1 6 0.8 No
33 46.0 15 3.0 Yes
34 102.6 7 1.2 No
35 15.8 15 2.2 No
36 60.0 7 1.3 No
37 96.4 13 2.6 No
38 24.2 14 1.7 No
39 14.5 15 2.4 No
40 36.6 14 1.5 No
41 65.7 5 0.6 No
42 116.3 7 1.6 No
43 113.6 8 1.0 No
44 16.7 15 4.3 Yes
45 66.0 7 1.0 No
46 60.7 7 1.0 No
47 90.6 7 0.7 No
48 91.3 7 1.3 No
49 14.4 18 3.1 Yes
50 72.8 14 3.0 Yes")
attach(df)
lab <- sprintf("%.1fcm, %dyr", Height, Age)
plot(Age ~ Height, main="The Title", pch=20, xlab="Height in cm", ylab="Age in years")
text(y=Age, x=Height, labels=lab, cex=.7, col=rgb(0,0,0,.5), pos=4)
detach(df)
```

And with the help of `wordcloud::textplot()`:

```
if (!require(wordcloud)) {
  install.packages("wordcloud")
  library(wordcloud)
}
plot(Age ~ Height, main="The Title", pch=20, xlab="Height in cm", ylab="Age in years", type="n")
textplot(y=Age, x=Height, words=lab, cex=.5, new=F, show.lines=T)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ggplot2` library. Example -

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, label=rownames(mtcars)))+
geom_point() + 
geom_text()
```

What that code snippet is doing is taking the 'mtcars' dataset, assigning the x variable as the `wt` column, the y variable as the `mpg` column, and the labels as the `rownames`. `geom_point` adds a scatterplot based on the above x,y, and `geom_text` places the labels at the x,y coordinates.

Check out the help entry on `geom_text` to see the formatting options.

Answer (score 0):

#### Examples taken from [ggplot2 documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/ggplot2.pdf), page 98

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, label=rownames(mtcars)))
p + geom_text()
# Change size of the label
p + geom_text(size=10)
p <- p + geom_point()
# Set aesthetics to fixed value
p + geom_text()
p + geom_point() + geom_text(hjust=0, vjust=0)
p + geom_point() + geom_text(angle = 45)
# Add aesthetic mappings
p + geom_text(aes(colour=factor(cyl)))
p + geom_text(aes(colour=factor(cyl))) + scale_colour_discrete(l=40)
p + geom_text(aes(size=wt))
p + geom_text(aes(size=wt)) + scale_size(range=c(3,6))
# You can display expressions by setting parse = TRUE. The
# details of the display are described in ?plotmath, but note that
# geom_text uses strings, not expressions.
p + geom_text(aes(label = paste(wt, "^(", cyl, ")", sep = "")),
parse = TRUE)
# Add an annotation not from a variable source
c <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()
c + geom_text(data = NULL, x = 5, y = 30, label = "plot mpg vs. wt")
# Or, you can use annotate
c + annotate("text", label = "plot mpg vs. wt", x = 2, y = 15, size = 8, colour = "red")
# Use qplot instead
qplot(wt, mpg, data = mtcars, label = rownames(mtcars),
geom=c("point", "text"))
qplot(wt, mpg, data = mtcars, label = rownames(mtcars), size = wt) +
geom_text(colour = "red")
# You can specify family, fontface and lineheight
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, label=rownames(mtcars)))
p + geom_text(fontface=3)
p + geom_text(aes(fontface=am+1))
p + geom_text(aes(family=c("serif", "mono")[am+1]))
```