# Boxplots/histograms for multiple variables in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, histogram

I have a big dataset with +100 observation and 68 variables.
I was wondering whether there might be a way to generate plots and histograms for all those variables at once without having to write down the code for a boxplot/histogram one by one, and save them in a folder as pns or in a pdf.

possibly I'd like to have more than one plot on the same page (i know you can do that using "par")

I know is probably a simple piece of coding but it would be really helpful for me.
Thank you

Ok I think an example could be the data from the iris dataset:

> "Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
>
> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
>
> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
>
> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
>
> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
>
> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
>
> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa"

But instead of having just "Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width " as observed variables, I  have 68 of them.
My interest is to check normality distribution for the sample on all my 68 variables and boxplot . I know how to create boxplots and histogram variable per variable, but that would take a lot of time and I  imagine there must be a way to do it at once, probably using a loop or a %>% ?

Comment: Please create a short reproducible example including some data and an example output if possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. We don't need your actual data, just a representative example or a built in data set would be fine. Exactly what is the desired output? A PDF? A single image?

Comment: @WannabeGandalf: this might help too https://stackoverflow.com/a/59791424/786542

Comment: https://boxuancui.github.io/DataExplorer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `DataExplorer`, `skimr` and `inspectdf` packages. They all produce summaries like the one you want. These articles give an overview:
https://www.littlemissdata.com/blog/simple-eda
https://www.littlemissdata.com/blog/inspectdf